# Replace column with the most recently available data (replace nested forloop with purrr)

Tags: r, foreach, purrr, dplyr

**Translating nested STATA forloops into R tidyverse/purrr syntax**

I am trying to do this using foreach or purrr, but I keep getting stuck.

> STATA Code:

```
foreach v in zip income child{
g `v`_agg="" **generate an empty column with the specified name (e.g. address_agg or income_agg)**
foreach l in 20190601 20180401 20171001 20160801{
replace `v'_agg=`v'`l' if missing (`v'_agg) **replace agg variable with the latest version if missing**
}
}
```

> Here is the data example:

```
zip20190601 zip20180401 zip20171001 zip20160801 income20190601 income20180401 income20171001 income20160801 child20160801 child20171001 child20180401 child20190601
1     NA           11440        12016        15686           75038           63573           82391           47517              0              1              1              2
2     13089        12626        13670        16155           89494           64984           62603           47252              0              1              1              2
3     13258        12249        13333        16819             NA               NA           48231           45729              0              1              1              2
4     NA           NA           18480        18611           89480           67348           55516           45863              0              1              1              2
5     13990        10497        12573        13406           70053           63850           87833           48332              1              2              2              3
6     17005        11491        15227        17518           78087           70741           46318           47823              1              2              2              3
7     17174        17006        13461        11189           76780           66649           54578           46196              1              2              2              3
8     12452        15317        18049        14284           76654           73583           70090           48281              0              1              1              2
9     18449        14262        11013        17810           91422           79722           53948           45986              0              1              1              2
10    11429        11731        13564        14603           84282           60190           45133           46956              0              1              1              2


structure(list(zip20190601 = c(NA, 13089L, 13258L, NA, 
13990L, 17005L, 17174L, 12452L, 18449L, 11429L), zip20180401 = c(11440L, 
12626L, 12249L, NA, 10497L, 11491L, 17006L, 15317L, 14262L, 
11731L), zip20171001 = c(12016L, 13670L, 13333L, 18480L, 12573L, 
15227L, 13461L, 18049L, 11013L, 13564L), zip20160801 = c(15686L, 
16155L, 16819L, 18611L, 13406L, 17518L, 11189L, 14284L, 17810L, 
14603L), income20190601 = c(75038L, 89494L, NA, 89480L, 
70053L, 78087L, 76780L, 76654L, 91422L, 84282L), income20180401 = c(63573L, 
64984L, NA, 67348L, 63850L, 70741L, 66649L, 73583L, 79722L, 
60190L), income20171001 = c(82391L, 62603L, 48231L, 55516L, 
87833L, 46318L, 54578L, 70090L, 53948L, 45133L), income20160801 = c(47517L, 
47252L, 45729L, 45863L, 48332L, 47823L, 46196L, 48281L, 45986L, 
46956L), child20160801 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0), child20171001 = c(1, 
1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1), child20180401 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 1, 1), child20190601 = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 2, 2, 
2)), .Names = c("zip20190601", "zip20180401", "zip20171001", 
"zip20160801", "income20190601", "income20180401", "income20171001", 
"income20160801", "child20160801", "child20171001", "child20180401", 
"child20190601"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

> **Goal:**

I am trying to create a current "agg" variable for each of the variables (zip_agg, child_agg, income_agg) by running a for loop through the different dated variables to replace values from the most recent data.

If the most recent version is missing, it should go back to the next latest date. I have started to code it out but I know this is incorrect.

```
variable_date<-c("20190601", "20180401", "20171001", "20160801")
variable_list<-c("zip", "income", "child")


# using foreach package
foreach(x=variable_list, .combine = 'cbind') %:%
  foreach(y=variable_date, .combine = 'c') %do%
  { 

    var_agg<-str_c(x, "_agg") #create variable name

my.df%<>%
      mutate(var_agg=NA,
      var_agg=ifelse(is.na({{var_agg}})==T, my.df[str_c(x,y)], {{var_agg}}))
```

Expected output

[image]

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Just updated with expected output!

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps, an option is to reshape into 'long' format and then do the `filter` or `slice` based on the last date

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(stringr)
df1 %>%
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "date"), names_sep="_") %>%
    group_by(rn) %>%
    slice(which.max(date)) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    rename_all( ~ str_c(., '_agg')) %>%
    bind_cols(df1, .)
```

---

If we don't need the `NA` i.e. if the last element is `NA` based on the date, then an option is to `summarise` after `arrange`ing by 'date'

```
df1 %>% 
    mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "date"), names_sep="_") %>% 
    arrange(rn, date) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(zip:child), ~ last(.[!is.na(.)])) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    rename_all( ~ str_c(., '_agg')) %>%
    bind_cols(df1, .)
#zip_20190601 zip_20180401 zip_20171001 zip_20160801 income_20190601 income_20180401 income_20171001 income_20160801 child_20160801
#1            NA        11440        12016        15686           75038           63573           82391           47517              0
#2         13089        12626        13670        16155           89494           64984           62603           47252              0
#3         13258        12249        13333        16819              NA              NA           48231           45729              0
#4            NA           NA        18480        18611           89480           67348           55516           45863              0
#5         13990        10497        12573        13406           70053           63850           87833           48332              1
#6         17005        11491        15227        17518           78087           70741           46318           47823              1
#7         17174        17006        13461        11189           76780           66649           54578           46196              1
#8         12452        15317        18049        14284           76654           73583           70090           48281              0
#9         18449        14262        11013        17810           91422           79722           53948           45986              0
#10        11429        11731        13564        14603           84282           60190           45133           46956              0
#   child_20171001 child_20180401 child_20190601 zip_agg income_agg child_agg
#1               1              1              2   11440      75038         2
#2               1              1              2   13089      89494         2
#3               1              1              2   13258      48231         2
#4               1              1              2   18480      89480         2
#5               2              2              3   13990      70053         3
#6               2              2              3   17005      78087         3
#7               2              2              3   17174      76780         3
#8               1              1              2   12452      76654         2
#9               1              1              2   18449      91422         2
#10              1              1              2   11429      84282         2
```

#### Update

If there are no separation in the names, we can still use a regex lookaround to separate within `names_sep`

```
df2 %>% 
    mutate(rn =row_number()) %>% 
    pivot_longer(cols = -rn, names_to = c(".value", "date"),
        names_sep="(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])") %>% 
    arrange(rn, date) %>% 
    group_by(rn) %>% 
    summarise_at(vars(zip:child), ~ last(.[!is.na(.)])) %>%
    ungroup %>%
    select(-rn) %>%
    rename_all( ~ str_c(., '_agg')) %>%
    bind_cols(df2, .)
#   zip20190601 zip20180401 zip20171001 zip20160801 income20190601 income20180401 income20171001 income20160801 child20160801 child20171001
#1           NA       11440       12016       15686          75038          63573          82391          47517             0             1
#2        13089       12626       13670       16155          89494          64984          62603          47252             0             1
#3        13258       12249       13333       16819             NA             NA          48231          45729             0             1
#4           NA          NA       18480       18611          89480          67348          55516          45863             0             1
#5        13990       10497       12573       13406          70053          63850          87833          48332             1             2
#6        17005       11491       15227       17518          78087          70741          46318          47823             1             2
#7        17174       17006       13461       11189          76780          66649          54578          46196             1             2
#8        12452       15317       18049       14284          76654          73583          70090          48281             0             1
#9        18449       14262       11013       17810          91422          79722          53948          45986             0             1
#10       11429       11731       13564       14603          84282          60190          45133          46956             0             1
#   child20180401 child20190601 zip_agg income_agg child_agg
#1              1             2   11440      75038         2
#2              1             2   13089      89494         2
#3              1             2   13258      48231         2
#4              1             2   18480      89480         2
#5              2             3   13990      70053         3
#6              2             3   17005      78087         3
#7              2             3   17174      76780         3
#8              1             2   12452      76654         2
#9              1             2   18449      91422         2
#10             1             2   11429      84282         2
```

Comment: Is it possible to specify the variables on the fly?

Comment: @brin You meant `variable_date<-c("20190601", "20180401", "20171001", "20160801");
variable_list<-c("zip", "income", "child")`

Comment: Thank you! I just realized my data does not have "_" between the variable name and variable date. How can I reshape the file to long without specifying a separator? I have edited the question to reflect the correct column headers.

Comment: @brin try with `names_sep = "(?<=[a-z])(?=[0-9])"`

Answer (score 0):

We can use `max.col` here. We divide the operation into two parts, first where we want to calculate the latest value for all `"zip"` and `"income"` columns and the second part where we want to calculate max value from `"child"` columns.

```
variable_list <- c("zip", "income")

#Part 1 
df[paste0(variable_list, '_agg')] <- lapply(variable_list, function(x) {
     cols <- grep(x, names(df))
     df[cols][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(!is.na(df[cols]), ties.method = "first"))]
})

#Part 2
cols <- grep('child', names(df))
df$child_agg <- df[cols][cbind(1:nrow(df), max.col(df[cols]))]

#Result
df[13:15]

#   zip_agg income_agg child_agg
#1    11440      75038         2
#2    13089      89494         2
#3    13258      48231         2
#4    18480      89480         2
#5    13990      70053         3
#6    17005      78087         3
#7    17174      76780         3
#8    12452      76654         2
#9    18449      91422         2
#10   11429      84282         2
```

Comment: What if I had more variables like Child or more character variables?

Comment: @brin So similar like "zip" and "income" columns we can use `lapply` there as well so that it can be done for many number of columns.